# Tomcat running on Amazon EC2 not accessible outside AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, elastic-ip

Have found plenty of answers to this question but nothing seems to be working.

I have a windows `EC2` instance which has tomcat 8 installed and running on port `8080`. I have my application deployed and I am able to access it as `localhost:8080/myapp` by connecting to the instance and launching the url in browser.

However, when I try to access it over my home network outside aws, the application is not able to connect.

I know this is because of `security group` settings but I have that covered. Even after I do

> Security Groups -> Inbound -> Edit:
>
> Custom TCP Rule : TCP: 8080 : Source Anywhere

The problem still remains. Have even tried adding a rule with `all traffic` but still no luck.

Also, to mention, I have an `Elastic IP` associated to my instance. Have been trying to access with `elastic.ip:8080/myapp` but not able to connect.

What else could I try? Any configuration in tomcat's `xml` ?

Comment: have you checked any ACL applied on that. also  you can modify elastic search policy settings and add your ip. if its related to elasticsearch.

Comment: its not at all related to elastic search. I mentioned Elastic IP.

Comment: I assume there is nothing wrong with NACL since it allows all traffic by default. Have you defined multiple rules in Security Group?

Comment: Yes, just one more. `TCP:80:Anywhere`

Comment: Can you spin up another instance that has a public ip, then connect to it. Try to call the private ip within that instance

Comment: I have another question @roger_that. You have said that you connected to the instance to check if the web server is running. With current 2 rules how did you connect? 3389 port needs to be enabled in order to RDP right.

Comment: Yeah. I mean I did enabled TCP 3389 as well to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Image the instance and launch a new instance from the created AMI.

EC2 appears to be experiencing issues over the past 12 hours where the public interface of some instances won't accept traffic, even though other instance launched with the exact same Launch Configuration (in my case as part of an Auto Scaling Group) have no problem.

If you have premium technical support, I suggest you leave the bad instance running and file a ticket with the instance ID, public IP address, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if "wget" working or not. If yes, meaning the tomcat server is up & running.

`wget <hostname>:8080`

Also Your computer at home might have a firewall which prevents you from retrieving port 8080. Can you try telnet to the server at port 8080 from your home machine?

Finally check IPtables on the server as well:-

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure tomcat isn't only listening on `127.0.0.1:8080`. Which would make it available to localhost but not elsewhere. Look in your `server.xml` for the connectors address and make sure it's set to `0.0.0.0` to listen on all interfaces:

```
# Example
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           address="0.0.0.0" />
```

You can also look at the output of `netstat -an | grep :8080` you should see a line like

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

If instead you see

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

You know that it's only listening on `127.0.0.1` which won't be available outside your local host.

Comment: added the same. however, the connector entry has one more field `redirectPort=8443`. Anything to do with that?

Comment: This is what I get after netstat
`TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`
  `TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:53417        ESTABLISHED`
  `TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:53419        ESTABLISHED`
  `TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         127.0.0.1:53420        ESTABLISHED`
  `TCP    127.0.0.1:53417        127.0.0.1:8080         ESTABLISHED`
 `TCP    127.0.0.1:53419        127.0.0.1:8080         ESTABLISHED`
`TCP    127.0.0.1:53420        127.0.0.1:8080         ESTABLISHED`

Comment: It would appear based on this line `TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING` that its listening on all addresses like you need. The redirect port should only matter if the request is HTTPS